# Pandas datareader 'iex-last' results in "failed to interpret response as JSON"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader

I'm trying to get the last price for TLT from iex. It was working when I tried it last month, but when I tried it today I was met with the error:

```
TypeError: Failed to interpret response as JSON
```

The code I'm using is:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data

tlt_price = data.DataReader('TLT', 'iex-last')
```

I tried using the example on the docs page that reads:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
f = web.DataReader('gs', 'iex-tops')
f[:10]
```

But the same error occurs.
Any idea how to get it working again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, from the pandas-datareader documentation
You must provide an API Key when using IEX

`EX.os.environ["IEX_API_KEY"] = "pk_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`

Then, I simply got my token by creating an account on https://iexcloud.io

Finally my df was like

```
start = datetime(2017, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2017, 12, 31)
df = web.DataReader('TSLA','iex',start,end)
```